# How this code is running without any return value at the end in java? Please Explain?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

can you please explain to me this code why we don't have any return type in this and the code is still working fine?

```
public static void printBetweenK1K2(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root, int k1, int k2) {
    
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (root.data >= k1 && root.data <= k2) {
        System.out.println(root.data);
    }
    
    if (root.data > k1) {
        printBetweenK1K2(root.left, k1, k2);
    }
    
    if (root.data <= k2) {
        printBetweenK1K2(root.right, k1, k2);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *"we don't have any return type"*: you just replaced the code completely and now the function **has** a return type. What are you up to? You still have a question?

Comment: Don't entirely change your question once you've gotten an answer.

Comment: It doesn't have a return type because it isn't returning anything. It is just printing data so there's no need to return any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` methods in java don't need to return a thing. Read [this](http://www.beginwithjava.com/java/methods/void-methods.html) for better understanding.

Comment: And, as a comment on the naming - one would not necessarily expect a method named 'printSomething' to be returning a value anyway.

Comment: actually I added the wrong code can please check this one